# OSMNX - trying to plot graph in console without any luck

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, osmnx

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

G = ox.graph_from_point((37.79, -122.41), dist=750, network_type='all')
ox.plot_graph(G)
plt.show()
```

I am simply trying to plot a simple figure in the console, but there is no output at all. The above code is written in a script. Anyone that knows what the issue is?

Platform: Spyder (Python 3.8)

Comment: Provide some details about your platform and how you're running the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. To make the plots appear in the Console, I had to uncheck "Mute Inline Plotting" under Plots pane options menu.